# How to deinterlace and concatenate with filter complexe

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to deinterlace and concatenate. The concat part is functioning, but I can't find how to insert the yadif filter in the sequence. With the command bellow, I'm breaking the concatenation...

```
ffmpeg ^
-y ^
-i video1.mpg ^
-i video2.mpg ^
-itsoffset 20 ^
-i logoSE.png ^
-filter_complex "[1:v]yadif; [0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vv][a]; [vv][2:v]overlay=W-w-10:10[v]" ^
-map "[v]" ^
-map "[a]" ^
-c:s "copy" ^
-pix_fmt yuv420p ^
-c:v libx264 ^
-crf 21 ^
-x264opts keyint=30:min-keyint=1:bframes=3:ref=4:scenecut=-1:colorprim=bt709:transfer=bt709:colormatrix=bt709:force-cfr ^
-b:v 16M ^
-minrate 6.6M ^
-maxrate 18.5M ^
-bufsize 8M ^
-f mpegts ^
-streamid 0:481 ^
-streamid 1:129 ^
-mpegts_start_pid 481 ^
-mpegts_pmt_start_pid 27 ^
-muxrate 20M ^
-preset medium ^
-tune film ^
-profile:v high ^
-level:v 4.1 ^
-metadata:s:a:0 language=fre ^
-s 1920x1080 ^
-r 30000/1001 ^
-vsync 1 ^
-c:a ac3 ^
-b:a 448K ^
-ar 48000 ^
-ac 6 ^
output_video.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter_complex will change to

```
"[1:v]yadif[1v]; [0:v][0:a][1v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vv][a]; [vv][2:v]overlay=W-w-10:10[v]"
```

When you wish to send the output of a filter to another filter, you should label the output pad of the first filter (assigned `1v` here) and then ingest that in the destination filter.

Comment: Great, thank you! It's working.